# Improving the run time and style of string compare method java?

Tags: java, string, sorting

I am trying to solve this problem: 
Write a function to check if two strings are the same length. 
If either string contains any numbers, those numbers are added to the length. 
Ex:
    "ab2" & "aabb" //true
    "hhhsss" & "12" //false
    "hello" & "sarah" //true
    "2abc" & a1a1a" //true

This is my code, it works but its slow, repetitive, too wordy and less efficient than it should be. I'm a beginner and looking for tips on how to improve this. Thanks in advance!

```
public static boolean pattern(String a, String b) {
    char A[] = a.toCharArray();
    char B[] = b.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(A);
    Arrays.sort(B);

    int i = 0;
    int timesA = 0;
    int lengthA = 0;
    while (i < A.length && Character.isDigit(A[i])) {
        lengthA += A[i];
        timesA++;
        i++;
    }
    lengthA += A.length - timesA;

    int j = 0;
    int timesB = 0;
    int lengthB = 0;
    while (j < B.length && Character.isDigit(B[j])) {
        lengthB += B[j];
        timesB++;
        j++;
    }
    lengthB += B.length - timesB;

    return lengthA == lengthB;
}
```

Comment: Create a method to compute the length of **one** String. Then call that method twice (once for each string). Then compare the two lengths. Transforming to an array and sorting the characters of the string is useless to do what you need to do. All you need is to loop through the characters and test if they are a number. Your code is incorrect by the way, since it stops the loop as soon as it finds a on-digit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs at [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What are the numbers in  "text15"? A one and a five (summing to six)? Or a fifteen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do some changes in your overall strategy.

You do not neet to sort the two strings in the beginning.

Create four  variables: a counter and a digit buffer for each string.

Loop over each char of the two strings and if it is:

**a digit** :  concatenate the digit to the respective buffer

**not a digit** : add 1 to the respective counter. Also, evaluate the respective buffer as a number and add the result to the counter. Empty the buffer.